# Problem Posting json data to API using Axios in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to create a Axios request where i will post json data. The format of the data will be

```
{"qBody":"aaa","qAnswer":"bbb","qOptions":[],"qType":"GAP","qClass":6,"qSubject":1,"qChapter":1,"qCreatorid":1,"qCreatorrole":"admin"}
```

But it is posting as

```
{"data":{"qBody":"aaa","qAnswer":"bbb","qOptions":[],"qType":"GAP","qClass":6,"qSubject":1,"qChapter":1,"qCreatorid":1,"qCreatorrole":"admin"}}
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
var data = {
              "qBody" : question,
              "qAnswer" : trueFalseAnswer,
              "qOptions" : qOptions,
              "qType" : questionCategory,
              "qClass" : className,
              "qSubject" : subjectName,
              "qChapter" : chapterName,
              "qCreatorid" : qCreatorid,
              "qCreatorrole" : qCreatorrole
            };

    const newData =  JSON.stringify(data)
    
     this.$axios.post("http://128.199.192.87:8081/api/v1/questions/add",{
                  newData
                },{
                  'Content-Type': "application/json"
                }).then((response)=>{
                  console.log(response)
                })
```

How can I make the format correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Comment: When you say *"it is posting as..."* do you mean: *"that's what I see in the browser console"*?

Comment: No. It is from Request Payload in Network Tab of developers Option of the browser

Comment: Could you please create a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io (or a similar service), making sure it reproduces the described behavior? What you're saying is close to impossible.

Answer (score 2):

What you are `console.log()`-ing is not what you're sending. It is the response that's getting back from the server. If you want to log what you're sending, use:

```
console.log(newData);
```

... just before making the POST request.

Most likely, you don't need to stringify the request.

What you're seeing in the console is the server response. According to the [*response-schema*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema) in their documentation, the server's response data is placed in the `.data` property of the response object.

So, apparently, the server sends back the same data. With most servers, this means no error has occurred.

---

In fewer words, you are not sending your data wrapped as `{ data: ... }`. If you were, you would be getting back: `{ data: { data: ... } }`

Comment: I have posted the above json from Request Payload in Network Tab of developers Option of the browser. I tried skipping stringify the data.